# How to add rows to a repeater in client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a `Repeater` and also a `Button`. If I click on my button a new rows need to be created to the repeater in client side (Javascript). I am able to do this with server side, but want to avoid a postback. I am not using an Ajax `Updatepanel` control. Moreover I am using a table structure in my `Repeater`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Repeater` is just producing a table, here is some javascript to add a row to a table.

```
function AddRowToTable()
{  
    // Add your table name to the getElementById
    var table = document.getElementById("yourTableID");  
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    // Create any cells and elements you need
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");  
    element1.type = "text";  
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    // repeat for more cells / elements as required
}
```

This will just add it client side though so if you want it to postback you will need to store the data using elements that will post their data.