# New row in asp:repeater by java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

In my aspx page I have repeater to show list something, I want to add new row and show it in repeater without postback. I will send date soon. I don't want to use AJAX

How to add row to asp:repeater by JavaScript?

Comment: You can do this, but it will not be accessible on the server side.  What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have dropdownlist and checkboxlist. After change dropdownlist checkboxlist gets new values. I have to remember selected checkboxes (with information about dropdownlist value) and show it in repeater

Comment: So why can't you use AJAX, i.e., an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446166/how-to-add-rows-to-a-repeater-in-client-side

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is inpect the code using a tool like firebug retrieve the html for the row, and recreate that using javascript and attach it to the DOM. Dirty but doable. Using something like jquery will make your work easier.

I know you dont want to use AJAX but the cleanest method would be to use an UpdatePanel and do is on the server side using a partial postabck

Answer (score 0):

The repeater just generates repeating html so it's definitely possible to insert new html by using javascript. As @mellamokb mentions those changes won't be visible on the server side.

It's generally a bad idea to mix client and server side rendering with ASP.NET Webforms.

In the case of a list of some kind being dependent on e.g. a combobox it's often a better idea to render lists for *all* options in the ASPX code. Then use javascript to hide every list except the currently active one.