# How to add new row to repeater without losing information in checkboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have a simple Repeater that contains a checkbox and a Full name per each row.
In addition, I have an "Add Name" button that adds a new full name to the database.

Supposingly user checks a few checkboxes and decides to add another name, I would like to be able to add a new name to the repeater without losing the information in the checkboxes that have been already checked.

I understand some javascript code might do the trick the question is how to approach it? 
What do I do?

thanks in advance

p.s.
I'll be glad to hear any advice, not olny regarding js.

Comment: You should be more precise, maybe give sample code, for us to understand the issue you experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick solution, not very pretty but get the job done. Hope it will give you some new ideas

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RepeaterCheckbox
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        List<Person> personsFromDatabase
        {
            get { return (List<Person>)ViewState["persons"]; }
            set { ViewState["persons"] = value; }
        }

        //here we will store our person selection state
        Dictionary<int,bool> personSelectionState
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<int, bool>)ViewState["data"]; }
            set { ViewState["data"] = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                #region Test data
                personsFromDatabase = new List<Person>{
                    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Paul", },
                    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Tom", },
                };
                #endregion

                Bind(false);
            }
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        void Bind(bool isPostback)
        {
            if (!isPostback)
            {
                //initialize person selection mapping
                personSelectionState = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
                foreach (Person person in personsFromDatabase)
                personSelectionState.Add(person.Id, false);
            }

            //map persons to anonymous type that will help us define necessary values
            rpPersons.DataSource = personsFromDatabase.Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                //get stored selection state for person
                Selected = personSelectionState[x.Id],
            });
            rpPersons.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnAddPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //update selection states
            UpdateSelectionStatuses();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txbName.Text))
            {
                //add new person
                personsFromDatabase.Add(new Person
                    {
                        Id = personsFromDatabase.Count +1,
                        Name = txbName.Text,
                    });

                //add status mapping for new person so there is no error on postback binding
                personSelectionState.Add(personsFromDatabase.Count, false);

                //Refresh data on page, to see new person
                Bind(true);
            }
        }

        void UpdateSelectionStatuses()
        {
            //loop through all items
            for (int i = 0; i < rpPersons.Items.Count; ++i)
            {
                RepeaterItem repeaterItem = rpPersons.Items[i];

                //find checkbox for item
                var checkbox = (CheckBox)repeaterItem.FindControl("chbSelected");
                if (checkbox != null)
                {
                    //get our custom attribute
                    int id = int.Parse(checkbox.Attributes["personId"]);

                    //update stored checkbox status
                    personSelectionState[id] = checkbox.Checked;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void rpPersons_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var item = e.Item.DataItem;

                var checkbox = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chbSelected");
                if (item != null && checkbox != null)
                {
                    //get person id from our helper anonymous type
                    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] anonymousTypeProperties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                    int id = (int)anonymousTypeProperties.Where(x => x.Name == "Id").FirstOrDefault().GetValue(item, null);

                    //set custom attribute on checkbox to map checkbox with person
                    checkbox.Attributes["personId"] = id.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="RepeaterCheckbox._Default" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpPersons" OnItemDataBound="rpPersons_ItemDataBound" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <p>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chbSelected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Selected") %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' />
                    </p>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txbName" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddPerson" runat="server" Text="Add person" OnClick="btnAddPerson_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works great when I put it in a new form but when I insert that code into a form that is related to a master page, the form wouldn't compile. Any ideas?

Comment: If you could post some code would be nice but I think that you should place repeater in asp page(container) not in masterpage. Hard to diagnose when I don't know anything about your site structure.

Comment: The problem was that in the "Default.aspx.cs" code I had to change the "ViewState" to "Session". And then it works as a charm for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how do you approach it. Are you using the asp.net repeater in an Ajax update panel?
If is the case you can save check box value at each click event this way when you add a new item the control will be rebinded with the updated values.

If you like to use client side javascript thie post could help you:
[How to add rows to a repeater in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446166/how-to-add-rows-to-a-repeater-in-client-side)